# Could we use 'COULD HAVE' for speculation in the past ?

Tags: modal-verbs

Could we use 'COULD HAVE' for speculation in the past ? Are the examples below correct?

> In the very heart of Europe, Austria is a country which **could have** been created with activity holidays in mind.
>
> A source involved in the investigation says airline **could have** broken up at around 35000 feet.
>
> Though the drain was barely 2 feet deep, the water pressure **could have** pushed him into the reservoir

Answer (score 2):

That usage is correct. In all contexts, the past modal "could have" is speculating about the past.

In your second example, however, I think you are missing the article "the", and I'd recommend using "airplane" or "plane" instead of "airline"

Comment: could we use 'may have and might have' instead of could have in the above context?

Comment: Yes, in this case you can. There is a bit more info on those slight differences here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64374/might-have-vs-could-have